# How to de-identify BigQuery data that stored in RECORD or REPEATED properties?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dlp

I'm trying to build a Dataflow pipeline that de-identifies data from the BigQuery table. I'm building *com.google.privacy.dlp.v2.Table* object and passing it to the ContentItem like that:

```
List<Field> fieldList = new ArrayList<>(
                bigquery
                        .getTable(table)
                        .getDefinition()
                        .getSchema()
                        .getFields());
  
    List<Table.Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    for (FieldValueList bigQueryRowItem : bigquery
            .listTableData(table)
            .getValues()) {
        Table.Row row = convertBigQueryRowToTableRow(bigQueryRowItem);
        rows.add(row);
    }
    Table dlpTable = Table
            .newBuilder()
            .addAllHeaders(convertFieldsToHeaders(fieldList))
            .addAllRows(rows)
            .build();
```

But unfortunately, this *fieldList* contains only first-level BigQuery properties without RECORD or REPEATED ones. Please advise me on how to get all fields' names from the table efficiently, including RECORD/REPEATED, and how to convert the BigQuery values to the  *Table.Row* efficiently?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is done one of two ways:

Flatten the fields into columns. So  a record

```
  RecordA {Field1, Field2} becomes 2 columns, RecordA.Field1 and RecordA.Field2
```

For the repeated fields you can do the same or concat the field values together into a single cell.

```
RecordA { Field1: {value1,value2,value3] } becomes 3 columns .... RecordA.Field1[0], RecordA.Field2[1], and RecordA.Field3[2]
```